# How can modify the "src" tag of an image to data-src with js or jquery in order to enable lazy loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

In order to use most lazy loading libraries we need to use "data-src" instead of just "src" 
How can i modify the html and "src" to be data-src to be able to use  lazy loading.

I CANT change the html code to data-src because we sharing components and what this change only on one page.

So my question is, once i do view page source i want to see the data-src instead of just src

I was  able to edit the DOM and see my changes in view page source when i used this line of code

```
$("a[href='/comprehensive-insurance-and-collision-coveragee']").prop('href', '/comprehensive-insurance-and-collision-coverage')
```

it basically edited the link of from coveragee to coverage. 
and when i did view page source i can see the link as coverage not coveragee,

i want to the same thing as that but for src to data-src

Answer (score 2):

You can’t, since JavaScript makes changes to the DOM: there are several ways to change the attribute from `src` to `data-src`, but you won’t see it right in the sources. You can only see it inspecting the page with the browsers’ developer tools. You need back-end languages such as PHP to automatically make a server-side change.

In jQuery:

```
var source = $(element).attr("src");
$(element).attr("data-src", source).removeAttr("src");
```

In vanilla JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");
var source = element.getAttribute("src");
element.setAttribute("data-src", source);
element.removeAttribute("src");
```

But you can’t directly change the page sources. Changes stay in the DOM, so I guess this won’t work for lazy loading. You should consider a server-side language to make changes to that page, IMHO, unless the libraries are loaded *after* a script like those.

Comment: I was about halfway through a similar answer lol. Basically, since the `src` is already loaded as a visible object, the HTTP request is already made, negating the benefits of lazy loading.

Comment: can you look at my update, i have changed the javascript in the past and in view page source i see the change as well.

Comment: If it works in view-sources too, then the first jQuery snippet should do the trick! Just remember to do it in an `onload` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In case that you don‘t want to modify the src-attribute as it‘s being used in different contexts, you could add the loading=lazy attribute instead to lazy load images (and iframes if needed). Additionally to support older browsers as well, you could use the polyfill that I‘ve developed for this aspect: https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill